# Converting yfinance dataframe into multi-index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert this dataframe(df_long) into a multi-index dataframe (df_wide)

Imported this data from yfinance. New to python so would really appreciate the help :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssi73.png)

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the multi-index, use `.reset_index()`:

```
df_long.pivot_table(index=["Data"], 
                columns='tickers', 
                values='grade').reset_index()
```

[pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)